# showing Cursor Data on ListView using Cursor loader in Android

Tags: android

I am working on a task where I need to get the data from SQLite database and show it on a list view.I know that we can extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` and Override `getView()` method to show the data on list view,but I have seen in developers site that in 3.0 where we can use cursor loader to show data on list view, but it was said that Cursor Loader is used only for querying `ContentProviders`.Can I use Cursor Loader for querying SQLite DataBase. If so how can I do this, plz help me with some sample code...

Answer (score 0):

As per Android API documentation, Cursor Loader is mainly for querying content providers and not for SQLLite queries and explicity saying if data is not content (shared between applications) use SQLLiteDatabase. So, I would strongly discourage using CursorLoader for SQLLite operations.

Comment: Hii thinksteep thank you for the reply,the problem is I have very huge data.Is there a way to run background thread and show data on list view because  SimpleCursorAdapter uses UI thread.

Comment: You want to display huge data in a list? It may slow down/crash your app if data is too large. I would suggest think about alternative approaches. Another thing you may consider is, Java threading (if you really want to implement threading) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Answer (score 0):

CHeck this sites:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/525313/Using-Cursor-Loader-in-Android 
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/ 
also you can find that questions helpful:
[Show Progress Indicator before fill listview using CursorLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088499/show-progress-indicator-before-fill-listview-using-cursorloader) 
[ListView with CursorLoader and SimpleCursorAdapter isn't displaying data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981373/listview-with-cursorloader-and-simplecursoradapter-isnt-displaying-data) 
[Load data from multiple loaders/cursors into a listview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082951/load-data-from-multiple-loaders-cursors-into-a-listview-in-android)