# ListView with CursorLoader and SimpleCursorAdapter isn't displaying data

Tags: android

I'm trying to populate a ListView with data from a query using a CursorLoader. I'm new to CursorLoaders and I'm using code I purloined from Beginning Android 4 Application Development. As you can see, I'm getting data from an Intent. The data in the Intent is what I want; I've verified that in the debugger. However, when I query my database, nothing displays in the ListView. Can anyone help?

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static final String TABLE_BASEPATH = "tbl";
private static final String AUTHORITY = "SQLData";
public static final Uri MY_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + TABLE_BASEPATH);    

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent myData = getIntent();
    Bundle info = myData.getExtras();

    if (info != null){
        Cursor c;
        String[] dataColumns = { "mycolumn" };
        String selection = "level = '" + info.getString("Level") + "'";

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
            c = managedQuery(MY_URI, dataColumns, selection, null, "ORDER BY mycolumn");
        else
        {
            CursorLoader cursorloader = new CursorLoader(this, MY_URI, dataColumns, selection, null, "ORDER BY mycolumn");
            c = cursorloader.loadInBackground();
        }

        int[] viewIDs = { R.id.mylist1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.mylist, c, dataColumns, viewIDs);
        else
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.mylist, c, dataColumns, viewIDs, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, MY_URI,
            PROJECTION, null, null, null);  
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    switch (loader.getId()) {
      case LOADER_ID:
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        break;
    }

}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
```

It doesn't matter if I'm using the cursor or the CursorLoader. If my version is < 11 (cursor), I get no data; if it's > 11 (CursorLoader) I still get no data.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the code that you have posted, but you didn't post much... Please add the 3 CursorLoader methods to your question, the problem could be there. (Though I am curious why you are not simply using the Support Library for backwards compatibility.)

Comment: Well, that's probably because I don't know what I'm doing. ;) I'm an Android noob. My app works with cursors, but I'm trying to upgrade to CursorLoaders and am having a devil of a time. Just don't get what's going on here. And I don't know what you mean by the Support Library; please elaborate. I have the CursorLoader methods in my Activity, but they don't do anything. I don't know what they're supposed to do. I've been searching the web and nothing makes sense to me. A simple example would be very, very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that when I run my query I see in my LogCat the message "Failed to find provider info for SQLData". SQLData is my class that defines my database. I thought that was a provider. Do I have to define a custom content provider for my database?

Comment: Sam - here are my 3 CursorLoader methods, for what it's worth:

Comment: public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
  return new CursorLoader(this, MY_URI,
          PROJECTION, null, null, null); 
 }

 public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
  switch (loader.getId()) {
       case LOADER_ID:
         mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
         break;
     }

 }

 public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
  mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
  
 }

Comment: I am writing up an example of a CursorLoader (with the Support Library), however if you don't have a ContentProvider this will be difficult... And please click the "edit" button in the lower left corner of your question to add the CursorLoader methods to your question.

Comment: I've added the 3 CursorLoader methods to my question also, as requested. And thank you!

Comment: So I added some example code, but the CursorLoader will require a ContentProvider to you database. Have you written one?

Comment: No, I haven't. That's another hurdle I need to go through, I guess. That'll be for Monday. ;) And thank you for the code you posted below. It's very helpful; I'll implement it and then move on to the ContentProvider. I'll also download the Support Library if I don't already have it.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put in the id column in the projection when working with ContentProviders, otherwise they "won't work". Which I think you are doing > api level 11...

```
String[] dataColumns = { "mycolumn" };
```

The above code should include the id field. If the id field is "_id" (like Sams answer):

```
String[] dataColumns = { "mycolumn", "_id" };
```

Comment: Thank you, Niclas. I didn't realize that was a requirement here.