# Load data from multiple loaders/cursors into a listview in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I'am loading data into listview from cursors by initiating multiple loaders. I want my listview to show the data from all cursors but data in listview is changing immediately with a 2 seconds interval and showing data of only last cursor. Please help me. Where iam going wrong? Do I have to merge the cursors?

Inside onCreateView() of my fragment :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < idsArray.length; i++) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("id", idsArray[i]);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(idsArray[i], b, this);  //initiating multiple loaders
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_row, null, column_names_array, ui_ids_array, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And loader callback methods :

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle b) {
    Builder uriBuilder = MY_PROVIDER_URI.buildUpon();
    uriBuilder.appendPath("categories"); 
    uriBuilder.appendPath(String.valueOf(b.getInt("id")));  
    uriBuilder.appendPath("data");
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uriBuilder.build(), null, null, null, null); 
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if(adapter != null && data != null){ 
        adapter.swapCursor(data); 
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    } 
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

And here is my adapter class :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
Cursor cursor;
Context context;
Activity activity;
int layout;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags ) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    this.cursor = c;
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = (Activity) context;
    this.layout = layout;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(this.layout, parent, false);
}    

@Override 
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    if (holder == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //finding UI elements in list row here
        view.setTag(holder);
        }  
         //binding data to views of viewholder here
     } 

    static class ViewHolder {
    //variables of all my UI elements
     }
  }
```

Comment: If you call _adapter.swapCursor(data)_ the current cursor will be replaced, you should load all the wanted data inside one Cursor created by a single Loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < idsArray.length; i++) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("id", idsArray[i]);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(idsArray[i], b, this);  //initiating multiple loaders
}
```

will result in creating multiple Loaders, once a Loader has finished loading its data, the method

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if(adapter != null && data != null){ 
        // This line result in replacing the last Cursor by the new one
        adapter.swapCursor(data); 
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    } 
}
```

is invoked. When the last Loader has finished loading the Cursor, its data will replace the last Cursor because of **swapCursor**.

If you look at the [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) documentation, you will notice that this CursorAdapter can only manage one Cursor at a time.

To resolve your problem, you should try to query all the wanted data into a single query, resulting in a single Cursor.

Comment: Thanks. Got my mistake. Do I have to merge all the cursors created by loader?